# Unable to initialize a stack size to 0

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack

I'm a little rusty on using stacks so there might be something obviously wrong here. I'm either getting a segfault when I try to set my stack size to 0 I'm getting a segfault in my push function when the first if statement executes. The code below will segfault in the first line of push function.

```
typedef strcut Stack{
    Node data[UNIT_MAX];
    int size;
 } Stack;

//
Stack* DFS(Node* G, int numbVertices, Node v){
    //...More code above
    Stack* S = NULL;

    //Segfaulting when I try to set S->size = 0!!!

    push(S,v);


}

//
void push(Stack* S, Node d){
    if(S->size < UNIT_MAX){
        S->data[S->size++] = d;
    }
    else
        exit(STACK_FULL);
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `->` on a null pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Stack* S = NULL;

//Segfaulting when I try to set S->size = 0!!!
```

Certainly your program crash because you set S is NULL.

(Stack*)(NULL)->size = 0. It is sure to crash because you access the NULL address.